# How to install mpfr-3.1.2 in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, libraries, make

I have Ubuntu 13.04 with processor "Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E8400 @ 3.00GHz × 2 "

I m trying to install `mpfr-3.1.2` but the error is coming.

```
"ERROR! The versions of gmp.h (5.1.3) and libgmp (5.0.5) do not match."
```

In `make` command also it is showing this as warning.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 13):

Availble `mpfr` version for 13.04 is `3.1.1-1`. See [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=raring&arch=any&searchon=sourcenames&keywords=mpfr) for information.

You can install it by :

```
sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev libmpfr-doc libmpfr4 libmpfr4-dbg
```

Comment: i downloaded the mpfr version 3.1.1-1 and than installed it but again it is giving error ............"ERROR! The versions of gmp.h (5.1.3) and libgmp (5.0.5) do not match." .. :(

Comment: result of apt-cache madison libgmp..... "N: Unable to locate package libgmp"

Comment: Soory..Please post the result of `apt-cache madison libgmp10` and `apt-cache madison libgmp-dev`. How ever just test with the `sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev libmpfr-doc libmpfr4 libmpfr4-dbg`. Not need to Give Y to install. test with upto that.

Comment: result of apt-cache madison libgmp10 is .... " libgmp10 | 2:5.0.5+dfsg-2ubuntu3 | http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main i386 Packages
       gmp | 2:5.0.5+dfsg-2ubuntu3 | http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main Sources"
and the result for apt-cache madison libgmp-dev is .... "libgmp-dev | 2:5.0.5+dfsg-2ubuntu3 | http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main i386 Packages
       gmp | 2:5.0.5+dfsg-2ubuntu3 | http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main Sources"

Comment: So `gmp` and `libgmp` are installed from main repository. From where you downloaded the `mpfr3.1.1-1`?. If you try with `apt-get install` most of the time it can resolve. I am afraid.

Comment: i got it from .. "https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mpfr4/3.1.1-1"  ... and than i am installing it by following the install file in the directory.

Comment: Launchpad repositories and the Ubuntu main repository do having mismatches in certain times. Here it can be the problem. You should either add that repository which given that downloaded file and install with it or install with this method.

Comment: ok...i will do the same. thank you very much for giving me direction and your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build `mpfr` from source. It depends on `gmp`.
The version of the header and the library do not match, since they are being read from different places.

To avoid this, you can suitably `configure` the build.
You will see in the output of `configure` whether the versions of
`gmp.h` and `libgmp` match or not,
there is no need to get the error from `make`.

For a proper configuration, run

```
./configure --prefix=<location where to place mpfr> --with-gmp=<location where to look for gmp>
```

where

`<location where to place mpfr>` is anything you want. E.g., system directories, if you have rights to install there, or under your home directory. I used `$HOME/usr/local`, for instance.

`<location where to look for gmp>` is where `gmp` is installed. It seems there are two versions of `gmp` in your system due to the mismatch mentioned in comments. Either solve that, or build/install your own `gmp`.